# Date validation. Keeps looping even though my date is actually valid

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++-cli, do-while

I tried entering an invalid date which is 4 31 2007(April is the 4th month on the calendar and only have 30 days on it) and my code did what it suppose to do but why does my do while loop keep looping even though I entered a valid date?

```
class test
{
    int nmonths;
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

public: 
    test()
    {
        int x;
        do
        {
            cout << "Enter the date of most recent test (mm dd yyyy) (Ex. 01 
09 2011):" <<endl;
            cin >> month >> day >> year;
            int days;
            if ( month < 1 || month > 12 )
            {
                cout << "INVALID DATE!!!" << endl;

            }
            if ( month == 4 || month== 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
            {
                days = 30;
                if( day < 1 || day > 30)
                {
                    cout << "INVALID DATE!!!" << endl;
                    x = 0;
                }
            }
            if ( month == 2)
            {
                bool leapyear = (year% 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 
400 == 0);
                if (leapyear == 0)
                {
                    days = 28;
                    if (day < 1 || day > 28)
                    {
                        cout << "INVALID DATE!!!" << endl;
                        x = 0;
                    }       
                }
                else 
                    days = 29;
                    if ( day < 1 || day > 29 )
                    {
                        cout << "INVALID DATE!!!" << endl;
                        x = 0;
                    }
            }
            else 
            {
                days = 31;
                if ( day < 1 || day > 31)
                    {
                        cout << "INVALID DATE!!!" << endl;
                        x = 0;  
                    }
            }

        }while(x == 0);
};
```

This is the photo of output I'm getting
[image]

Comment: What is your condition to leave the loop? And how is `x` supposed to become `!= 0`? Magic?

Answer (score 1):

You never set `x` to a non-zero value.
Try adding `x = 1;` before the `cin`.